# How can I refer a file (xml/xsl/txt) from an included dependent jar into my code?

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-3, maven-plugin

I made a jar of my code say `ABC.jar` using maven, which has a class `ABC.class` from which I want to access a file say 'need.xml' which is present in a dependent jar say `XYZ.jar` inside `src/main/resources/xmls/need.xml`

How can I do that? I want to achieve this so that I can have the latest copy of `need.xml` always whenever it is updated inside `XYZ.jar`

Comment: I believe you could try something like `ABC.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream('need.xml')`

Comment: no it did not work for me says... can not resolve type

Comment: How about ABC.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream('xmls/need.xml')?

Comment: Sounds like a strange error. Is that compile time?

Comment: @ArunM I used xmls/need.xml....

Comment: What's the exact error that you got when you used xmls/need.xml

Comment: ok, this is bit strange... but the jar does not have any class file.... it just contains the .xml files.... which in our case was ABC.class, the project structure is bit complex in nature .... so when I opened the jar using winrar it shows me only xml files..... that is why writing ABC.class was unable to resole